# Initializing text box value in jsp page with java variable

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page having two text field id and name. Now I want to Declare two java variable 
`int ID=5;` & `String Name="Riyana";`. I want to initialize the value of the text fields with these two java variable.How to do this? Please help.
This is my code segment of jsp page:

```
     <% 
        int ID=5;
        String Name="Riyana";
     %>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">ID</td>
        <td><input name="id" value="" size="20" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Name</td>
        <td><input name="name" value="" size="50" type="text"></td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   <%!   int ID=5; String Name="Riyana"; 
> %>
> ```
>
> value="<%=Name%>"

Please use <%! %>  for variable initialisation.

```
  <td align="right">Name</td> 
  <td><input name="name" value="<%=Name%>" size="50" type="text">
  </td>       
</tr>
```

Do not use scriptlets, try the taglibs instead.

Comment: but i got error after using this. the error shows can't find symbol variable name

Answer (score 1):

I would ***strongly*** suggest you **[not to use Java code in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)**, its bad MVC design.

You should pass these variable from [`servlet`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) and on jsp use [`jstl`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to access variables

how ever for your code solution is here.

```
<%!  

 int ID=5; 
 String Name="Riyana"; 

%>

<input name="name" value="<%=Name%>" size="50" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td align="right">Name</td> 
    <td><input name="name" value='<%=Name%>' size="50" type="text">
</td>
```

Use single quotes in the value of the input text, like `value='<%=Name%>'` instead of double quotes like `value="<%=Name%>"`

Answer (score 1):

Use jstl

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>   
<c:set var="ID" value="5"/>   
<c:set var="Name" value="Riyana"/>   
<td align="right">Name</td>    
<td><input name="name" value="${Name}" size="50" type="text"></td>
```